# Как поменять заголовок приложения скомпилированного через pyinstaller?

Tags: python, компиляция, pyinstaller

После компиляции *.py* файла через *pyinstaller*, заголовок скомпилированного (терминальное) приложения:

**C:\Users\user\Example.exe**

как сделать так, чтобы на заголовке было только:

**Example**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте библиотеку ctypes

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW("Example")
```